# jQuery only used at 480px ViewPort (inline labels for mobile)

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a login screen that uses adaptive CSS so that the labels in the login form appear inline over the field on an iPhone to save real estate. At other resolutions the labels appear to the left of the field.

I found this tutorial, but I don't really know jQuery. I need to manipulate the code from the tutorial so that this technique only fires for mobile.

Here's the tutorial for inline labels using jQuery:
http://www.zurb.com/playground/inline-form-labels

I've got the CSS and Adaptive Principles down, it's just the jQuery where I lack knowledge, so specific instructions will help me catch up to speed.

Here's the specific jQuery that I only need to fire if mobile is detected:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("label.inlined + input.input-text").each(function (type) {

    Event.observe(window, 'load', function () {
      setTimeout(function(){
        if (!input.value.empty()) {
          input.previous().addClassName('has-text');
        }
      }, 200);
    });

    $(this).focus(function () {
      $(this).prev("label.inlined").addClass("focus");
    });

    $(this).keypress(function () {
      $(this).prev("label.inlined").addClass("has-text").removeClass("focus");
    });

    $(this).blur(function () {
      if($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).prev("label.inlined").removeClass("has-text").removeClass("focus");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You're page 404's.

You can check window width and do your calculations based on it:

```
if($(window).width() <= 480)
```

You can monitor the resize event to check for window resizing too:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() { ... });
```

e.g.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if($(window).width() <= 480) {
    $("label.inlined + input.input-text").each(function (type) {

      Event.observe(window, 'load', function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
          if (!input.value.empty()) {
            input.previous().addClassName('has-text');
          }
        }, 200);
      });

      $(this).focus(function () {
        $(this).prev("label.inlined").addClass("focus");
      });

      $(this).keypress(function () {
        $(this).prev("label.inlined").addClass("has-text").removeClass("focus");
      });

      $(this).blur(function () {
        if($(this).val() == "") {
          $(this).prev("label.inlined").removeClass("has-text").removeClass("focus");
        }
      });
    });
  }
}).resize();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bad URL. I've updated the tutorial link and I've added the jQuery that will help me place labels inline. The piece I'm missing is only firing this script when mobile is detected. 

This site using an adaptive approach, so when it's at a full desktop resolution the jQuery should not take effect.